# Dynamic columns from two tables

Tags: sql, sql-server

i need some help. I would like to combine two tables in sql with dynamical columns.
Here my thoughts:

Table one:

```
select processname, step, steplabel, username, incident, indate, outdate, status from jrincidents
```

[Example Table jrincidents](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QbVoN.png)

Table two:

```
select username, department from jrusers
```

[Example Table jrusers](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6P1M6.png)

[reporting like](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QLcv6.png)

i don't know how to dynamically add the steplabels from table jrincidents as columns of jrusers if where processname = x

Thanks for helping

ADD:

Let me try again

The Result should look something like that

[Result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JE6VJ.png)

```
select distinct a.department, 
(select count(b.incident) from Auswertungsvorlage_Prozess as b where b.processname = 'rechnungseingang' and b.department = a.department ) as Anzahl,
(select avg(datediff(MINUTE,n.indate,n.outdate)) as avg_min from Auswertungsvorlage_Prozess as n where n.processname = 'rechnungseingang' and n.department = a.department and n.steplabel ='Erfassung und Verteilung ') as Erfassung_und_Verteilung,
(select avg(datediff(MINUTE,c.indate,c.outdate)) as avg_min from Auswertungsvorlage_Prozess as c where c.processname = 'rechnungseingang' and c.department = a.department and c.steplabel ='Handelspartner / Bank anlegen') as Handelspartner_Bank_anlegen,
(select avg(datediff(MINUTE,d.indate,d.outdate)) as avg_min from Auswertungsvorlage_Prozess as d where d.processname = 'rechnungseingang' and d.department = a.department and d.steplabel ='Sachliche Prüfung') as Sachliche_Prüfung,
(select avg(datediff(MINUTE,e.indate,e.outdate)) as avg_min from Auswertungsvorlage_Prozess as e where e.processname = 'rechnungseingang' and e.department = a.department and e.steplabel ='Freigabe') as Freigabe,
(select avg(datediff(MINUTE,f.indate,f.outdate)) as avg_min from Auswertungsvorlage_Prozess as f where f.processname = 'rechnungseingang' and f.department = a.department and f.steplabel ='Prüfung durch den Einkauf') as Prüfung_durch_den_Einkauf,
(select avg(datediff(MINUTE,g.indate,g.outdate)) as avg_min from Auswertungsvorlage_Prozess as g where g.processname = 'rechnungseingang' and g.department = a.department and g.steplabel ='Rückfrage zur Rechnung') as Rückfrage_zur_Rechnung,
(select avg(datediff(MINUTE,h.indate,h.outdate)) as avg_min from Auswertungsvorlage_Prozess as h where h.processname = 'rechnungseingang' and h.department = a.department and h.steplabel ='Rechnung abweisen') as Rechnung_abweisen,
(select avg(datediff(MINUTE,i.indate,i.outdate)) as avg_min from Auswertungsvorlage_Prozess as i where i.processname = 'rechnungseingang' and i.department = a.department and i.steplabel ='Buchung') as Buchung,
(select avg(datediff(MINUTE,j.indate,j.outdate)) as avg_min from Auswertungsvorlage_Prozess as j where j.processname = 'rechnungseingang' and j.department = a.department and j.steplabel ='DocuWare Indexierung') as DocuWare_Indexierung,
(select avg(datediff(MINUTE,k.indate,k.outdate)) as avg_min from Auswertungsvorlage_Prozess as k where k.processname = 'rechnungseingang' and k.department = a.department and k.steplabel ='Protokoll anklammern') as Protokoll_anklammern,
(select avg(datediff(MINUTE,l.indate,l.outdate)) as avg_min from Auswertungsvorlage_Prozess as l where l.processname = 'rechnungseingang' and l.department = a.department and l.steplabel ='Anhänge anheften') as Anhänge_anheften,
(select avg(datediff(MINUTE,m.indate,m.outdate)) as avg_min from Auswertungsvorlage_Prozess as m where m.processname = 'rechnungseingang' and m.department = a.department and m.steplabel ='Übergabe an Infor') as Übergabe_an_Infor,
(select avg(datediff(MINUTE,o.indate,o.outdate)) as avg_min from Auswertungsvorlage_Prozess as o where o.processname = 'rechnungseingang' and o.department = a.department) as Zeit_Durchschnitt,
(select avg(datediff(MINUTE,p.indate,p.outdate)) * 10 as avg_cost from Auswertungsvorlage_Prozess as p where p.processname = 'rechnungseingang' and p.department = a.department) as Kosten
from Auswertungsvorlage_Prozess as a where a.processname = 'rechnungseingang';
```

The department and steplabel should be dynamic like a filter.

If i change the processname to "rechnungseingang" the select should chose the different steplabels and departments dynamic from a subtable row as a column in the select. Like a move from vertical(row) to horizontal(column).

Data Table:

```
department  step    steplabel   incident    indate  outdate processname
    1   Beschaffungsantrag erfassen 897 2020-09-22 12:07:44.000 2020-09-24 11:10:29.000 beschaffung
    7   A1 Entsendeantrag ergänzen  9   2020-05-19 14:33:05.000 2020-05-19 16:07:37.000 dienstreise
    7   A1 Entsendeantrag ergänzen  9   2020-05-19 16:07:37.000 2020-05-19 16:09:09.000 dienstreise
    10  Bestellung durch den Einkauf    61  2020-01-30 14:42:52.000 2020-02-05 13:08:18.000 beschaffung
    10  Genehmigung durch die GL    1   2020-01-14 10:39:15.000 2020-01-17 12:13:44.000 investantrag
    10  Genehmigung durch die GL    1   2020-01-17 12:13:45.000 2020-01-17 12:13:59.000 investantrag
    20  Info zur genehmigten Dienstreise    6   2020-01-27 12:54:16.000 2020-02-06 10:59:12.000 dienstreise
    20  Info zur genehmigten Dienstreise    17  2020-01-31 13:14:57.000 2020-02-06 10:59:12.000 dienstreise
    50  Info zur Bestellung 61  2020-02-05 17:50:15.000 2020-02-06 10:07:24.000 beschaffung
    50  Info zur Zahlung    2   2020-01-30 15:36:36.000 2020-02-06 10:29:50.000 zahlungsanweisung
    50  Info zur Zahlung    2   2020-02-06 10:29:50.000 2020-02-06 10:49:24.000 zahlungsanweisung
    50  Info zur Zahlung    2   2020-02-06 10:49:24.000 2020-02-06 10:49:59.000 zahlungsanweisung
AFS 1   Beschaffungsantrag erfassen 61  2020-01-27 11:40:45.000 2020-01-27 11:40:45.000 beschaffung
AFS 1   Beschaffungsantrag erfassen 82  2020-01-30 10:16:31.000 2020-01-30 10:16:31.000 beschaffung
AFS 1   Beschaffungsantrag erfassen 224 2020-03-02 11:13:42.000 2020-03-02 11:13:42.000 beschaffung
AFS 1   Beschaffungsantrag erfassen 363 2020-04-02 12:14:53.000 2020-04-02 12:14:53.000 beschaffung
AFS 1   Beschaffungsantrag erfassen 482 2020-05-13 07:36:30.000 2020-05-13 07:36:30.000 beschaffung
AFS 1   Beschaffungsantrag erfassen 784 2020-08-14 15:06:34.000 2020-08-14 15:06:34.000 beschaffung
AFS 1   Beschaffungsantrag erfassen 835 2020-09-01 08:03:53.000 2020-09-01 08:03:53.000 beschaffung
AFS 1   Beschaffungsantrag erfassen 955 2020-10-06 15:36:36.000 2020-10-06 15:36:36.000 beschaffung
AFS 1   Beschaffungsantrag erfassen 1035    2020-10-27 12:24:04.000 2020-10-27 12:24:04.000 beschaffung
AFS 1   Beschaffungsantrag erfassen 1077    2020-11-05 15:54:08.000 2020-11-05 15:54:08.000 beschaffung
AFS 20  Empfang der Ware bestätigen 82  2020-02-01 09:07:25.000 2020-03-13 10:54:14.000 beschaffung
AFS 20  Empfang der Ware bestätigen 61  2020-02-05 17:50:15.000 2020-02-28 08:45:47.000 beschaffung
AFS 20  Empfang der Ware bestätigen 224 2020-03-04 19:14:23.000 2020-03-13 10:53:56.000 beschaffung
AFS 20  Empfang der Ware bestätigen 482 2020-05-19 08:58:48.000 2020-10-06 14:54:46.000 beschaffung
AFS 50  Info zur Bestellung 61  2020-02-06 10:07:24.000 2020-02-28 08:45:08.000 beschaffung
AVK 1   Beschaffungsantrag erfassen 7   2020-01-13 15:51:45.000 2020-01-13 15:51:45.000 beschaffung
AVK 1   Beschaffungsantrag erfassen 62  2020-01-27 12:05:45.000 2020-01-27 12:05:45.000 beschaffung
AVK 1   Beschaffungsantrag erfassen 472 2020-05-08 11:01:24.000 2020-05-08 11:01:24.000 beschaffung
AVK 10  Sichtung & Bearbeitung  478 2020-08-04 09:31:38.000 2020-08-04 10:13:03.000 post
AVK 20  Empfang der Ware bestätigen 7   2020-01-22 09:03:42.000 2020-02-12 11:29:59.000 beschaffung
AVK 20  Empfang der Ware bestätigen 62  2020-01-28 16:40:02.000 2020-07-10 08:34:02.000 beschaffung
AVK 20  Empfang der Ware bestätigen 472 2020-05-12 11:39:46.000 2020-07-10 13:09:41.000 beschaffung
AVK 50  Info an Besteller   472 2020-05-12 11:39:46.000 2020-05-12 13:02:59.000 beschaffung
AVZ 1   Beschaffungsantrag erfassen 942 2020-10-02 09:37:05.000 2020-10-02 09:37:05.000 beschaffung
AVZ 1   Beschaffungsantrag erfassen 942 2020-10-02 09:50:02.000 2020-10-02 10:28:18.000 beschaffung
AVZ 1   Beschaffungsantrag erfassen 948 2020-10-06 08:23:32.000 2020-10-06 08:23:32.000 beschaffung
AVZ 1   Beschaffungsantrag erfassen 948 2020-10-06 09:09:27.000 2020-10-08 08:27:50.000 beschaffung
AVZ 1   Beschaffungsantrag erfassen 961 2020-10-08 08:35:53.000 2020-10-08 08:35:53.000 beschaffung
AVZ 1   Beschaffungsantrag erfassen 961 2020-10-08 10:00:39.000 2020-10-08 11:01:23.000 beschaffung
AVZ 1   Beschaffungsantrag erfassen 963 2020-10-08 11:10:28.000 2020-10-08 11:10:28.000 beschaffung
AVZ 1   Beschaffungsantrag erfassen 967 2020-10-12 07:51:45.000 2020-10-12 07:51:45.000 beschaffung
AVZ 1   Beschaffungsantrag erfassen 968 2020-10-12 07:57:36.000 2020-10-12 07:57:36.000 beschaffung
AVZ 1   Beschaffungsantrag erfassen 969 2020-10-12 11:09:48.000 2020-10-12 11:09:48.000 beschaffung
AVZ 1   Beschaffungsantrag erfassen 970 2020-10-12 14:22:04.000 2020-10-12 14:22:04.000 beschaffung
AVZ 1   Beschaffungsantrag erfassen 971 2020-10-12 14:24:19.000 2020-10-12 14:24:19.000 beschaffung
AVZ 1   Beschaffungsantrag erfassen 970 2020-10-12 15:25:05.000 2020-10-12 15:35:41.000 beschaffung
AVZ 1   Beschaffungsantrag erfassen 1036    2020-10-27 14:38:44.000 2020-10-27 14:38:44.000 beschaffung
AVZ 1   Beschaffungsantrag erfassen 1048    2020-10-29 10:25:16.000 2020-10-29 10:25:16.000 beschaffung
AVZ 1   Beschaffungsantrag erfassen 1051    2020-10-29 13:40:48.000 2020-10-29 13:40:48.000 beschaffung
AVZ 1   Beschaffungsantrag erfassen 1062    2020-11-03 17:38:40.000 2020-11-03 17:38:40.000 beschaffung
AVZ 1   Beschaffungsantrag erfassen 1075    2020-11-05 11:15:45.000 2020-11-05 11:15:45.000 beschaffung
AVZ 1   Einkaufsreklamation erfassen    1   2020-01-23 08:09:17.000 2020-01-23 08:09:17.000 ekreklamation
AVZ 1   Einkaufsreklamation erfassen    2   2020-01-23 08:23:23.000 2020-01-23 08:23:23.000 ekreklamation
AVZ 1   Einkaufsreklamation erfassen    3   2020-01-27 08:53:47.000 2020-01-27 08:53:47.000 ekreklamation
AVZ 1   Einkaufsreklamation erfassen    4   2020-01-31 08:48:38.000 2020-01-31 08:48:38.000 ekreklamation
AVZ 1   Einkaufsreklamation erfassen    8   2020-02-28 08:35:54.000 2020-07-09 15:42:31.000 ekreklamation
AVZ 1   Einkaufsreklamation erfassen    40  2020-09-02 09:29:52.000 2020-09-02 09:29:52.000 ekreklamation
AVZ 8   Rückfrage zur Reklamation   1   2020-01-23 15:16:59.000 2020-01-24 07:50:06.000 ekreklamation
AVZ 8   Rückfrage zur Reklamation   2   2020-01-23 15:18:06.000 2020-01-24 07:58:16.000 ekreklamation
AVZ 8   Rückfrage zur Reklamation   40  2020-09-11 11:06:20.000 2020-09-15 07:05:43.000 ekreklamation
AVZ 9   Info zur Reklamation    7   2020-01-17 08:43:14.000 2020-01-20 08:05:56.000 reklamation
AVZ 9   Info zur Reklamation    10  2020-01-21 13:11:57.000 2020-01-21 14:42:28.000 reklamation
AVZ 9   Info zur Reklamation    25  2020-03-02 13:56:48.000 2020-03-04 08:20:37.000 reklamation
AVZ 9   Info zur Reklamation    27  2020-03-04 08:16:26.000 2020-03-04 08:22:46.000 reklamation
AVZ 9   Info zur Reklamation    28  2020-03-05 08:46:19.000 2020-03-05 08:48:07.000 reklamation
AVZ 9   Info zur Reklamation    29  2020-03-05 10:34:45.000 2020-03-05 10:38:34.000 reklamation
AVZ 9   Info zur Reklamation    29  2020-03-05 10:34:46.000 2020-03-05 15:19:06.000 reklamation
AVZ 9   Info zur Reklamation    30  2020-03-06 08:26:01.000 2020-03-06 08:31:17.000 reklamation
AVZ 9   Info zur Reklamation    32  2020-03-12 13:11:21.000 2020-03-16 07:56:02.000 reklamation
AVZ 9   Info zur Reklamation    34  2020-04-06 08:10:50.000 2020-04-06 08:35:38.000 reklamation
AVZ 9   Info zur Reklamation    34  2020-04-06 08:10:51.000 2020-05-20 14:13:16.000 reklamation
AVZ 9   Info zur Reklamation    42  2020-05-20 14:03:33.000 2020-05-20 14:15:01.000 reklamation
AVZ 9   Info zur Reklamation    58  2020-08-31 08:07:24.000 2020-09-02 09:25:20.000 reklamation
AVZ 12  Stellungnahme zur Reklamation   1   2020-01-16 10:54:29.000 2020-01-21 14:42:02.000 reklamation
AVZ 12  Stellungnahme zur Reklamation   2   2020-01-16 10:55:10.000 2020-01-21 14:56:15.000 reklamation
AVZ 12  Stellungnahme zur Reklamation   22  2020-02-19 09:21:11.000 2020-02-21 12:02:54.000 reklamation
AVZ 12  Stellungnahme zur Reklamation   55  2020-08-11 14:32:50.000 2020-08-12 07:50:20.000 reklamation
AVZ 12  Stellungnahme zur Reklamation   55  2020-08-11 14:32:50.000 2020-08-31 08:09:32.000 reklamation
AVZ 18  Rückfrage zur Rechnung  2919    2020-06-04 14:21:52.000 2020-06-05 13:33:03.000 rechnungseingang
AVZ 20  Empfang der Ware bestätigen 967 2020-10-12 13:58:53.000 2020-11-03 16:28:18.000 beschaffung
AVZ 20  Empfang der Ware bestätigen 968 2020-10-12 15:33:38.000 2020-11-03 16:28:03.000 beschaffung
AVZ 20  Empfang der Ware bestätigen 969 2020-10-22 12:01:14.000 2020-11-02 15:28:52.000 beschaffung
AVZ 50  Info an Besteller   967 2020-10-12 13:58:53.000 2020-10-22 13:03:33.000 beschaffung
AVZ 50  Info an Besteller   968 2020-10-12 15:33:38.000 2020-10-22 13:03:18.000 beschaffung
AVZ 50  Info an Besteller   971 2020-10-12 16:23:39.000 2020-10-22 13:03:01.000 beschaffung
AVZ 50  Info an Besteller   970 2020-10-16 10:39:10.000 2020-10-22 13:02:46.000 beschaffung
AVZ 50  Info an Besteller   969 2020-10-22 12:01:14.000 2020-10-22 13:02:14.000 beschaffung
AVZ 50  Info zur Reklamation    2   2020-01-28 14:29:33.000 2020-03-05 15:19:34.000 ekreklamation
AVZ 50  Info zur Reklamation    4   2020-02-11 17:56:42.000 2020-03-05 15:19:54.000 ekreklamation
AVZ 50  Info zur Reklamation    1   2020-02-11 17:58:02.000 2020-03-05 15:20:14.000 ekreklamation
AVZ 50  Info zur Reklamation    3   2020-02-11 18:06:49.000 2020-03-05 15:20:40.000 ekreklamation
AVZ 50  Info zur Reklamation    8   2020-07-10 13:59:49.000 2020-07-13 07:31:59.000 ekreklamation
AVZ 50  Info zur Reklamation    40  2020-09-22 11:19:19.000 2020-09-22 12:59:27.000 ekreklamation
BLG 1   Bewegung von Anlagevermögen beantragen  1   2020-01-14 10:03:29.000 2020-01-14 10:03:29.000 anlagebewegung
BLG 1   Bewegung von Anlagevermögen beantragen  2   2020-01-14 10:04:44.000 2020-01-14 10:04:44.000 anlagebewegung
BLG 1   Bewegung von Anlagevermögen beantragen  3   2020-01-24 07:45:16.000 2020-01-24 07:45:16.000 anlagebewegung
BLG 1   Bewegung von Anlagevermögen beantragen  4   2020-01-27 11:20:56.000 2020-01-27 11:20:56.000 anlagebewegung
BLG 1   Bewegung von Anlagevermögen beantragen  5   2020-01-27 11:22:00.000 2020-01-27 11:22:00.000 anlagebewegung
```

Comment: Sorry, could not understand the required result. Please post sample table & expected result as text.

Comment: As I understand you need to pivot some column to column names and make some value column to be the value of corresponding row. If it is about reporting, then your reporting tool need to support Pivot Table or something similar, so just specify that column as column headings. Iv you need it in SQL, then you have to know which column to output. because in `pivot` clause of SQL you should specify the exact values to be exact column names.

Comment: That last image / report description is very confusing (for me). Please add the first few lines of the expected output. Also, please consider posting the sample data and the query you already have as text.

Comment: Sorry it's hard to explain... thanks for helping :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I wrote a procedure:

```
DECLARE @cnt INT = 0;                   
DECLARE @stepid INT = 0;                    
DECLARE @cnttable INT = 0;                  
DECLARE @steplabelname VARCHAR(500);                    
DECLARE @sqlCommand NVARCHAR(4000);                 
DECLARE @process varchar(75);                   
DECLARE @variable VARCHAR(10);                  
DECLARE @ParmDefinition NVARCHAR(500);                  
SET @process = 'rechnungseingang'                   
DECLARE @variabletemptable VARCHAR(20);                 
SET @variabletemptable = 'temprg'                   
                    
EXECUTE sp_refreshview 'Auswertungsvorlage_Prozess'                     
WHILE @cnt <= (select max(step) from Auswertungsvorlage_Prozess where processname =  @process)                  
BEGIN                   
    IF EXISTS (select distinct step from Auswertungsvorlage_Prozess where processname = @process and step = @cnt)               
        Begin           
                    SET @cnttable += 1
                    SET @variable = 'a'
                    SET @steplabelname = (select distinct REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(steplabel,' ', '_'),'_/_','_'),'_&_','_') from Auswertungsvorlage_Prozess where processname = @process and step = @cnt)+ '_' + CAST((select distinct step from Auswertungsvorlage_Prozess where processname = @process and step = @cnt) as varchar(10))
                    SET @sqlCommand = 'SELECT department, count(incident) ' + @steplabelname +', 
                    CAST(avg([dbo].[GetTotalWorkingMins](indate,outdate) -  [dbo].[GetMinProcess](step,processname,indate,outdate)) as decimal (18,2)) as Liegezeit_in_Minuten,
                    (CAST(avg([dbo].[GetTotalWorkingMins](indate,outdate) -  [dbo].[GetMinProcess](step,processname,indate,outdate)) as decimal (18,2)) / count(incident)) as Min_pro_STK,
                    (count(incident) * [dbo].[GetHours](step)) as Schrittzeit_Min,
                    (count(incident) * [dbo].[GetHours](step))/(221*435) as kalk_FTE,
                    (count(incident) * [dbo].[GetHours](step)) / (count(incident)) as Min,
                    count(incident) * CAST(([dbo].[GetHours](step) * [dbo].[GetCostMin](department)) as decimal (18,2)) as Summe_Kosten_Schritt,
                    (count(incident) * CAST(([dbo].[GetHours](step) * [dbo].[GetCostMin](department)) as decimal (18,2)) )/ count(incident) as Euro_Anz,
                    (count(incident) * CAST(([dbo].[GetHours](step) * [dbo].[GetCostMin](department)) as decimal (18,2))) / CAST(avg([dbo].[GetTotalWorkingMins](indate,outdate) -  [dbo].[GetMinProcess](step,processname,indate,outdate)) as decimal (18,2)) as Kosten_STK,
                    count(incident) * (CAST(avg([dbo].[GetTotalWorkingMins](indate,outdate) -  [dbo].[GetMinProcess](step,processname,indate,outdate)) as decimal (18,2)) + [dbo].[GetHours](step)) as Dauer_Gesamt_Total,
                    count(incident) * (CAST(avg(([dbo].[GetTotalWorkingMins](indate,outdate) -  [dbo].[GetMinProcess](step,processname,indate,outdate) ) * [dbo].[GetCostMin](department)) as decimal (18,2))) + count(incident) * CAST(([dbo].[GetHours](step) * [dbo].[GetCostMin](department)) as decimal (18,2)) as Kosten_Gesamt_Total '
                     + ' INTO ' +@variabletemptable +' from Auswertungsvorlage_Prozess ' + @variable + ' where processname = @process and step = @cnt group by department, steplabel, step'
                    SET @ParmDefinition = N'@cnt INT, @process NVARCHAR(75), @variable VARCHAR(10), @variabletemptable VARCHAR(20)'; 
                    EXECUTE sp_executesql @sqlCommand, @ParmDefinition ,@cnt = @cnt, @process = @process, @variable = @variable, @variabletemptable = @variabletemptable
                    SET @variable += 'a'
                    SET @variabletemptable += 'a'
        END         
   SET @cnt = @cnt + 1;                 
END                 
                    
GO
```

Answer (score 0):

If I understood right, you just want to add the column **steplabel** from **jrincidents** table to the **jrusers** table based on a condition.

Just try:

```
SELECT
    a.username, 
    a.department, 
    b.steplabel
FROM jrusers a LEFT JOIN jrincidents b ON a.username = b.username
WHERE b.processname = x
```

Comment: thanks for helping  :) , but that's not what i wanted with my question